# How to Push a JSON Array without the Index Keys?

Tags: arrays, json, database, firebase, push

I'm pretty new to **JavaScript** and need to create a **JSON** with number of keys and values (pushed into the variable `newWord`), without separating them. The thing is that I don't know what would be the length it in advenced (for that I am using a for loop to push each of the keys names and values):

```
    let langName = document.querySelectorAll('.langName');
    let langInput = document.querySelectorAll('.langInput');
    let newWord = new Array()
    for (let i = 0; i < langName.length; i++) {
        let l = langName[i].value;
        let w = langInput[i].value
        newWord.push({[l]: w})
    }
    firebase.database().ref(`content/words/`).push(
        newWord
    )
```

So, my result right now is:

[image]

While my desired result would be:

[image]

Does anyone know how do I get rid of the indexes (0, 1) and push a string key with a string value?

**Edit:  I want the for loop to add to the same object in this array, instead of creating a new object inside of it.**

Thanks!

Comment: `push` is used when you want to insert into a list. What you are looking for is `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push` is used to insert in a list in firebase database. Using set, you can store as key-value objects.

```
let langName = document.querySelectorAll('.langName');
let langInput = document.querySelectorAll('.langInput');
let newWord = {};
for (let i = 0; i < langName.length; i++) {
    let l = langName[i].value;
    let w = langInput[i].value
    newWord[l] =  w;
}
firebase.database().ref(`content/words/`).set(
    newWord
)
```